# Infinite loop in recursive Haskell function

Tags: haskell

Hmm... why does this function ends in an infinite loop when evaluating for any integer > 3?

```
smallestMultiple n = factors [2..n] where
factors [] = []
factors (h:xs) = h:(factors $ filter ((<)1) [div x h|x<-xs])
    where
      div x y
          |x `mod` y ==0 = x `div` y
          |otherwise = x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the main problem is that you define a local version of `div`:

```
div x y
  | x `mod` y == 0 = x `div` y
  | otherwise = x
```

Since bindings in `where` clauses (as well as in `let`) are recursive, the `div` on the right hand side of the first case refers to the same `div` you're defining! You can fix this by using a different name, like `div'`:

```
div' x y
  | x `mod` y == 0 = x `div` y
  | otherwise = x
```